# Quick conformation on joint probability theory question

Tags: probability

For a joint probably function given as

$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{5}{4}(x^2+y) & 0\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 2 \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$

Where the region is just a rectangle and I am asked to find $P(Y\leq 2)$, which is just equals 1 right? Likewise $P(X\leq 1) =1$ also. I am not sure if I am overthinking stuff or thinking about it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

You a describing a superset of the support, the probaility is $1$. We can't have $Y>2$ or $X>1$.